# What is AppRTC, how is it helpful for creating video call app for mobile?

Tags: javascript, java, webrtc, apprtc

I have developed a decent video calling application for web using **WebRTC** and **Javascript** which is working fine in both Chrome and Firefox. Now, a similar app is to be created for the mobile also (by the android devs in my company). I'm helping them out for the same. After a bit of research they could find out that it is possible using **AppRTC**. https://appr.tc/

So, now I'm setting up [this](https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc) in a dev server.

But my doubts are:

- [Here](https://webrtc.org/reference-apps/#) it is given as:

  > appr.tc is a webrtc demo application hosted on App Engine.

  What is this actually? I couldn't understand this. Is AppRTC just a sample application? Or, can it give specific response when accessed from mobile perspective?
- Is AppRTC really needed for creating video chat app for mobile? For web, I was able to access WebRTC API's using javascript. Is it possible to do the same in **Java** and create a mobile app without depending on AppRTC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AppRTC appears to simply be an example of an application built off of WebRTC.

There shouldn't be a reason you can't simply use WebRTC directly if you want, as that is the tech under AppRTC.

In case you didn't find it, here is the GitHub repo for it: https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc

For a native Java app, you can use the Android WebRTC package: https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/. That'll make it available via Java.

Comment: no, native code android still need Apprtc for room server :(

Comment: It doesn't *need* it. That is something you could implement yourself too. AppRTC could just provide a shortcut.

Comment: did you test that, the android app must to add appr.tc into setting for connect to room server!!!

Comment: I didn't test it, but the projects own description is "The video chat demo app based on WebRTC.". If it is a "demo" app, that means it implements things that can be implemented without it as well. It isn't a core technology like WebRTC. To use the AppRTC specific rooms, maybe you do. But that is not related at all to the original question of is it really needed.

Comment: appr.tc renders the webcom video on the browser and send the video to another peer. Is there an demo app that renders the webcam video (seeing yourself) and rendering the receiving MediaStream in a viewport?

Comment: What can I use as an alternative for apprtc room url?